# powershell XML Writer Nested Loop

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a powershell script that I'm trying to have build a lengthy XML file for an import.  The problem I'm having is that when run, the output to the XML has all of the open tags, but never closes them till the end.  Even though I have "WriteEndElement" functions to close out the tags in the order I want, it's not honoring those until all of the "WriteStartElement" tags are finished.  ie, the output would looks like

```
<1>
  <2>
    <3>
      <4>
      </4>
    </3>
  </2>
</1>
```

but in my code, the close of 3 should have come before the open of 4.
My script:

```
$groups = gc "./groups.txt"
$regions = gc "./regions.txt"
$types = gc "./Types.txt"

$output = "./Workgroups.txt"
$xmlOut = "c:\wgIMPORT.xml"
$wgExt = 60001


# Create The Document
$XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter($xmlOut,$Null)
# Set The Formatting
$xmlWriter.Formatting = "Indented"
$xmlWriter.Indentation = "4"
# Write the XML Decleration
$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
# Set the XSL
$XSLPropText = "type='text/xsl' href='style.xsl'"
$xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", $XSLPropText)
# Write Root Element
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Scenarios")
# Write the Document
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Scenario")
$xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Schedule","Immediate")



for($i=0;$i -lt $groups.Count;$i++){
    for($j=0;$j -lt $regions.Count;$j++){
        for($k=0;$k -lt $types.Count;$k++){ 
            #$groups[$i] + "_" + $regions[$j] + "_" + $types[$k] >> $output
            $wg = $groups[$i] + "_" + $regions[$j] + "_" + $types[$k]
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("WorkgroupCommand")
            $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Name","$wg")
            $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Extension","$wgExt")
            $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("HasQueue","1")
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Attributes")
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Attribute")
            $XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Value","206")
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement # end Attribute
            $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Value","TestSkill")
                $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement # end Attributes
            $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Members")
            $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Member","tonkaadmin")
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement # end  </Members> Command
            $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement # end Workgroup Command
            $wgExt++
        }
    }
}    

$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement # end Scenario
# Write Close Tag for Root Element
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement # end Scenarios
# End the XML Document
$xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument() 
# Finish The Document
$xmlWriter.Finalize
$xmlWriter.Flush
$xmlWriter.Close()
```

Comment: The structure of you'r output seems obvious, given the code. The only element that will open en close at the lowest level is `Members` and `Attribute`. Maybe if you would give the input files and an example of what you want, more people would answer.

Answer (score 3):

using

```
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
```

instead of

```
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement
```

should fix your problem